# i have a csv file and i need to calculate the time from csv column by powershell script

Tags: powershell

My CSV file data is like

```
"Time","remip","user","msg"
"01:10:47","10.16.2.49","efg","SSL tunnel established"
"01:12:47","11.16.2.34","abc","SSL tunnel established"
"01:13:10","11.16.2.34","abc","SSL tunnel shutdown"
"01:13:26","11.16.2.35","xyz","SSL tunnel established"
"01:13:40","10.16.2.49","efg","SSL tunnel shutdown"
"01:14:08","11.16.2.35","xyz","SSL tunnel shutdown"
```

Desired OUTPUT

```
"Time","remip","user","msg","Session Time"
"01:10:47","10.16.2.49","efg","SSL tunnel established",""
"01:12:47","11.16.2.34","abc","SSL tunnel established",""
"01:13:10","11.16.2.34","abc","SSL tunnel shutdown","1m:30sec"
"01:13:26","11.16.2.35","xyz","SSL tunnel established",""
"01:13:40","10.16.2.49","efg","SSL tunnel shutdown","2m:53sec"
"01:14:08","11.16.2.35","xyz","SSL tunnel shutdown","42sec"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Here is one way:

1. Convert csv to pscustomobjects.
2. Keep track of events in a hash table, and calculate timespan.
3. Convert back to csv.

### 1.

```
$csvdata = Get-Content infile.csv                      |
           ConvertFrom-Csv                             |
           select @{Name="Time"; Expression={[DateTime] $_.time}},
                  remip,
                  user,
                  msg,
                  @{Name="TimeSpan"; Expression={""}}
```

### 2.

```
$h = @{}
$csvdata | ForEach-Object {
  $key = $_.remip + ';' + $_.user; 
  if ($_.msg -like '*established') {
    $h[$key] = $_.time
    return
  } 

  if ($h.ContainsKey($key) -and $_.msg -like '*shutdown') {
    $_.timespan = $_.time - $h[$key]
    $h.remove($key)
  }
}
```

### 3.

```
$csvdata | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"Time","remip","user","msg","TimeSpan"
"8/17/2022 1:10:47 AM","10.16.2.49","efg","SSL tunnel established",""
"8/17/2022 1:12:47 AM","11.16.2.34","abc","SSL tunnel established",""
"8/17/2022 1:13:10 AM","11.16.2.34","abc","SSL tunnel shutdown","00:00:23"
"8/17/2022 1:13:26 AM","11.16.2.35","xyz","SSL tunnel established",""
"8/17/2022 1:13:40 AM","10.16.2.49","efg","SSL tunnel shutdown","00:02:53"
"8/17/2022 1:14:08 AM","11.16.2.35","xyz","SSL tunnel shutdown","00:00:42"
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly out put which i want thanks for briefing me the steps